# Sorting an array in order of users choice

Tags: arrays, sorting, computer-science

I wanted to know if I could sort an array not in lexicographic order but in an order asked by the user, as in, user has given some order and you are given an array, you need to sort the array in given order.

Comment: Which programming language?

Answer (score 0):

map the given order to a numerical one so if the user want  potatos, apples, oranges, map potatos to 1 apples to 2 annd oranges to 3